# Alignment and continuity of points in a matrix

Tags: matrices, nicematrix, extended-characters

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

I want to be able to extend the horizontal dots so that they fill the entire line and the spacing between the dots and the `x^n` is the same as between the dots and `x^2`. In addition, I would like to be able to extend the diagonal dots as well and to be able to orient them so that the 2 and the n! are "connected".

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [(c)]
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
            W(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n)=
            \begin{vmatrix}
                1 & x & x^2 & \cdots &  x^n \\
                0 & 1 & 2x & \cdots & nx^{n-1} \\
                0 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & n(n-1)x^{n-2} \\
                \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n! \\
            \end{vmatrix} \\
        \end{aligned} \\ [1ex] $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the package `nicematrix`  and add `\NiceMatrixOptions{renew-dots,renew-matrix}` before `\begin{vmatrix}`.

Adding the option `xdots/shorten=<length>` fixes the margin of both extremities of the lines as shown in second array.

If you have a document with a lot of math arrays with ellipses and you want to modify the dotted lines of **all of them**, you can put it in your preamble `\usepackage[renew-dots,renew-matrix]{nicematrix}`.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
        
\begin{enumerate}
    \item [(c)]
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
        W(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n)=
        \NiceMatrixOptions{renew-dots,renew-matrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{vmatrix}
            1 & x & x^2 & \cdots &  x^n \\
            0 & 1 & 2x & \cdots & nx^{n-1} \\
            0 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & n(n-1)x^{n-2} \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n! \\
        \end{vmatrix} \\
    \end{aligned} \\ [1ex] $
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
\item [(c)]
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    W(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n)=
    \NiceMatrixOptions{renew-dots,renew-matrix, xdots/shorten=0.6em}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & x & x^2 & \cdots &  x^n \\
        0 & 1 & 2x & \cdots & nx^{n-1} \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & n(n-1)x^{n-2} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n! \\
    \end{vmatrix} \\
\end{aligned} \\ [1ex] $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `nicematrix` package defines the `vNiceMatrix` environment. Unrelated: needless to load `inputencoding` nowadays; `utf8` is the encoding that latex expects by default.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [(c)]

        $\begin{aligned}[t]
            W(1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n)=
            \begin{vNiceMatrix}
                1 & x & x^2 & \Cdots & x^n \\
                0 & 1 & 2x & \Cdots & nx^{n-1} \\
                0 & 0 & 2 & \Cdots & n(n-1)x^{n-2} \\
                \Vdots & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & \Cdots & n! \\
            \end{vNiceMatrix} \\
        \end{aligned} \\ [1ex] $
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @F. Pantigny: thanks for the edit!